# Is this drive in 'My Devices' necessary?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 40 GB Volume in My Drives. It has folders like bin, boot, home, sys, root, etc stc. Can I delete the mentioned volume? So as to free up that much space? Or is it required to be there?

Any help is appreciated as I'm an Ubuntu n00b.

Thanks.

TenPlus1:

```
fdisk: invalid option -- '-'
Usage:
 fdisk [options] <disk>    change partition table
 fdisk [options] -l <disk> list partition table(s)
 fdisk -s <partition>      give partition size(s) in blocks

Options:
 -b <size>             sector size (512, 1024, 2048 or 4096)
 -c[=<mode>]           compatible mode: 'dos' or 'nondos' (default)
 -h                    print this help text
 -u[=<unit>]           display units: 'cylinders' or 'sectors' (default)
 -v                    print program version
 -C <number>           specify the number of cylinders
 -H <number>           specify the number of heads
 -S <number>           specify the number of sectors per track
```

Comment: Run Terminal and post the output of typing:  sudo fdisk -l

Comment: you Shouldn't Delete it

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 40 GB Volume in My Drives. It has folders like bin, boot, home, sys, root, etc

That is the equivalent to your C: drive in Windows (well not totally true but you get the drift?). Removing is would be deleting the operating system so no, it will not be possible to remove and get extra space.

> Or is it required to be there?

Yes and I would leave it there. It comes it handy if you need to quickly look at themes or fonts. Or to find an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is your system partition and you should not delete it. To determine, check the output of `mount`:

```
$ mount
/dev/md0p5 on / type reiserfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /boot type reiserfs (rw,notail)
/dev/sda2 on /windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/md0p6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=karimov-danil)
gvfsd-fuse on /home/karimov-danil/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

and the `fdisk -l`:

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/md0: 160.0 GB, 160048349184 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 39074304 cylinders, total 312594432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000318e5

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/md0p1            2048     8187903     4092928   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/md0p2         8189950   312592383   152201217    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/md0p5         8189952    47249407    19529728   83  Linux
/dev/md0p6        47251456   312592383   132670464   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005be20

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   156299263    78148608   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       156299264   311556095    77628416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *   311556096   312580095      512000   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe47dc70b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   156301311    78149632   83  Linux
```

In my example, Ubuntu is installed on `/dev/md0p5` which is shown in bold lines. If you find that your volume is also mounted on `/` you *definitely should not delete it*